# How to view XMLHttpRequest object

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest, cordova

I am new to JavaScript, so this is quite a basic question.

I am creating a `XMLHttpRequest` object and am calling the `setRequestHeader()` method. For debugging, I want to be able to see the headers I have set on the `XMLHttpRequest` object before I call `send()`.

There does not seem to be an API to `getRequestHeader()`, so is there another way to view my object as a string so I can debug?.

**Update:** Sorry, I need to make things clearer. I am writing a PhoneGap application and do not have access to a Chrome console.

Comment: can you not view in a chrome console by using the breakpoint options?

Comment: Sorry - this is in a PhoneGap application so I don't have access to Chrome console. Will update question.

Comment: I've got no experience with PhoneGap-development, but this might just help you: [Safari Remote Debugging and PhoneGap](http://www.raymondcamden.com/index.cfm/2013/1/21/Did-you-know--Safari-Remote-Debugging-and-PhoneGap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On chrome, use the network tab of the console, on firefox you may need firebug to do it, you'll see every informations about the xhr

Comment: Chrome's network tab is a fabulous tool, with the ability to record several requests in sequence and even filter to only view XHR requests if you need to. Firebug has similar functionality but does not feel as "smooth" as the one provided in Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

you can use (the available methods in) the `console` object to debug your scripts.

```
var object = {test:1};
console.log(object);
```

Reference: [console](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/console)

Comment: console.log() in PhoneGap gives me "[object XMLHttpRequest]" with no detail.

Comment: yeah, internet exploder and similarly simple browsers are no good for debugging. try a proper browser. :)